# tls connection set problem with docker and nginx containers

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm creating a container with nginx, I set the certificates, when I start the container it doesn't give me any errors but it doesn't set me up the tls connection.

the certificates are self-signed

nginx.conf file:

```
events{}
http{
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name  www.mydomain.it;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    }   
}
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx 
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

docker-compose yml

```
version: '3.8'

services: 
  nginx: 
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./
    ports : 
      - "80:80" 
      - "443:443"
    volumes: 
      - ./certs/:/etc/nginx/certs
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Please provide more info on what goes wrong. What does your browser indicate, when you go to the port? What does the log of NGINX container say?